# Allow traffic only if the packets match a string using iptables and ipsets

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables

I am attempting to allow traffic (ips in a ipset) only if the packets match a particular string. But I am not sure why it isnt working.

Firstly , I have blocked all the traffic. Then I allow only a certain set of IPs in the ipset.

The rule I have used is

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -j ACCEPT -p udp --dport 23456 -m set --match-set allowtest src -m string --algo bm --string "GameWare"
```

"allowtest" is my ipset. The traffic doesnt seem to pass through.

Comment: Your allow rules has to be before your block rule.  You said "First, i have blocked all the traffic".

Comment: Would changing -I to -A help?

Comment: 1. Flush the INPUT chain.    iptables -I INPUT 1  -j ACCEPT ......
iptables -I INPUT 2 -j DROP